# Why an opaque-enum-declaration is not a definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

§3.1/2 says that an *opaque-enum-declaration* is a declaration that is **not** a definition. Nevertheless it occupies space in memory. Compare it with a class **definition** that also has a size. Both are complete types by the Standard. Why one is a declaration and the other is a definition?

```
#include <iostream>
enum A : int;   // opaque-enum-declaration
class B{};      // a class definition

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(A) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(B) << '\n';
}
```

Output

> 4
>
> 1

**Edit**

The opaque-enum-declaration `enum A : int;` below is defined as far as I can understand.

```
#include <iostream>
enum A : int;   // opaque-enum-declaration

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

**Edit1**

As far as the variable `a` is concerned, there's no difference between the prior snippet and the one below. They both leave the variable undefined. Thus, it's difficult to accept that `enum : int;` is a declaration and `enum A : int {quick, brown, fox};` is a definition.

```
#include <iostream>
enum A : int {quick, brown, fox};

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Comment: While this probably isn't up to language lawyer rigor, think of the one *definition* rule: Would it make sense to restrict a program to only declare/define an opaque enum in one translation unit?

Comment: I does *not* occupy space in memory, but then again neither does a class definition...

Comment: I am starting to think that maybe I did not quite understand the question... there are two concepts, whether the type is *complete*, and whether it is *defined*, where the latter implies the former, but not the other way around... Is the question really whether it is *defined* or whether the type is *complete*?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas See my edit above

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: No, it is not *defined* according to the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type is *complete*, although not *defined* after an *opaque-enum-declaration*:

> 7.2 [dlc.enum]/3
>
> An opaque-enum-declaration is either a redeclaration of an enumeration
>   in the current scope or a declaration of a new enumeration. [ Note: **An
>   enumeration declared by an opaque-enum-declaration has fixed
>   underlying type and is a complete type.**( The list of enumerators can be
>   provided in a later redeclaration with an enumspecifier. —end note ] A
>   scoped enumeration shall not be later redeclared as unscoped or with a
>   different underlying type. An unscoped enumeration shall not be later
>   redeclared as scoped and each redeclaration shall include an enum-base
>   specifying the same underlying type as in the original declaration.

The **complete type** above means that you *can* use `sizeof` after just seeing the *opaque-enum-declaration*, which seems to be your concern. It is still not a *definition*, as a definition require all aspects of the type to be specified, which the *opaque-enum-declaration* does not.

If you were to compare this with a class definition, the *opaque-enum-declaration* would be the equivalent of a class [half] definition containing all non-static data members and an attribute stating whether virtual functions will be present, but without declaring any of the member functions.  The size of the object would be clear, but not how to use it.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: No, it is **not** defined, it declares a complete type, but it does not tell you what the enumerators are. See the last paragraph in this answer, size is *not* everything

Answer (score 2):

Size is only one aspect of an `enum`. Although it is enough for the compiler to know the size in order to let you use your `enum` in other declarations or definitions, the `enum` itself remains undefined until you enumerate its members. In essence, `enum A : int` promises the compiler two things - namely, that

- There is an `enum A` defined some place else, and
- All members of `enum A` will have values that fit in an `int`.

Once the compiler discovers the definition of `enum A`, it checks that the members are small enough for the declared size, and considers the `enum` defined. From that point on, providing another definition of the same `enum A` is an error.

In contrast, your `class B` is already fully complete: you told the compiler that `class B` is going to be empty; you cannot provide an alternative definition for it, giving it some members.

**EDIT :**

> The opaque-enum-declaration enum A : int; below is defined as far as I can understand.

`XYZ` is not considered defined until a point in your program after which providing a definition of `XYZ` constitutes an error. To that end, `enum A` remains undefined in your program, because you are allowed to define it after `main`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
enum A : int; // opaque-enum-declaration

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
// This is allowed
enum A : int {quick, brown, fox};
```

Incidentally, this does not prevent your program from compiling successfully, because in C++ *undefined* is not an equivalent of *unusable*.

Comment: `(in fact, you need to) provide a definition of your enum A` This compiles: `enum A::int; void f(A){} int main{ f(A(0)); }`

Comment: @WakeupBrazil This compiles, too: `class A; void foo(A* a) {} int main() {foo((A*)0);return 0;}`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Not exactly the same thing... your example would be closer to `enum class A : int; void f(A*) {} int main() { f((A*)0); }`. The difference being that in one case you are talking about a pointer and in the other about a value.

Comment: Coud you comment on this in §7.2/3: `An opaque-enum-declaration is either a redeclaration of an enumeration in the current scope or a declaration of a new enumeration`?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil This means that an opaque declaration could be the first mention of `enum A`, i.e. a new enumeration, and that it is also OK to put `enum A : int` after another declaration or after a definition of an enum ([demo](http://ideone.com/bg1kDd)), i.e. a redeclaration of an enumeration.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: `void f();` is either a redeclaration of a function or a declaration of a new function. Does this answer your last comment?

Comment: You almost convinced me with your Edit, but I still believe there's something missing in the Standard in relation to this entity, an opaque-enum-declaration.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I don't think I can agree with the recursive definition of *definition* in the edit. I could agree with that if stated in the opposite direction: *After an entity is defined, it cannot be later be redefined in the same translation unit*. But that does not define what *definition* means, only that it cannot be done multiple times in the same translation unit (i.e. it does not say what *definition* is, it imposes the restriction that whatever it is cannot be done twice in the same TU)

Comment: [...] on the other hand, it does solve part of the issue: if it *was* a definition, a later *opaque-enum-declaration* would be illegal. But that is somehow looking at the symptoms rather than the illness. The standard is clear: *opaque-enum-**declaration***, not **definition**. There is not much more to say there, is there? There seems to be a bit of confusion on whether the type being *complete* and *defined* are equivalent: they are not, more often than not they cover the same set but they are not the same.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I was trying to be as careful as I could to avoid a recursive definition of what is a definition by saying what is *not* a definition - in response to OP's suggestion that "`enum A` is defined because his program compiles." I think that the root cause of the OP's confusion is the unfortunate choice of words by the language standard: the word "definition" lacks a suitable opposite word. Saying that "`enum A` is undefined" suggests that the program that uses such an undefined type is invalid, which is not true.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I think that using the word "body" instead of "definition" would be a better choice of words: "XYZ is undefined" in the context of a programming language usually suggests that XYZ cannot be used. On the other hand, "XYZ lacks a body" does not suggest the same thing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: the *not-defined-ness* for uses of a type is *completeness* in the language. There are a limited set of things that you can do with an *incomplete* type. While the concept of *complete* and *defined* often go hand in hand, they are not the same and the few cases where they may differ can cause confusion. Again, consider a function: the declaration (not definition) allows the use, the definition is then required in the complete program, but you don't need the definition to be able to use the function.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
enum A : int;
```

is a declaration. It means that name A is declared to denote some scoped enumeration type. It does not occupy memory.

This statement

```
class B{};
```

is also a class declaration. It is called also a class definition because it defines the structure of the class. However this declaration does not occupy memory. It is an object of an enumeration or class type that occupies memory. These statement

```
std::cout << sizeof(A) << '\n';
std::cout << sizeof(B) << '\n';
```

show how many memory could occupy an object if it would be defined as having one of these types.

Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << sizeof( int ) << std::endl;
}
```

This code outputs the size of objects of type int. However neither object was defined in the program.

And compare the code above with the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int x;
   std::cout << sizeof( x ) << std::endl;
}
```

In this program an object of type x was defined. It does indeed occupy memory. int is only a simple type specifer. The same way A and B from your code are type specifiers. Type specifiers are only some desciptions. They do not occupy memory.